# Reference external clojurescript namespaces

Tags: namespaces, clojurescript, cljsbuild

If in a .cljs file I define a file like this:

main.cljs

```
   (ns project.main
      (:use [project.secondfile :only [my-var]]))

   (js/alert my-var)
```

secondfile.cljs

```
   (ns project.secondfile)
   (def my-var "Hi")
```

I get a "Referred var project.secondfile/my-var does not exist at src-cljs/main.cljs". However, it works normally in the browser as both are compiled (and with compilations :whitespace they can reference each other just fine). But obviously, it doesn't work in the bREPL as they aren't referring to each other.

Is this something unavoidable or I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code and works fine in my current configuration. 
I've had other issues similar to your question and in those cases you can try to compile and load the `secondfile.cljs` into the brepl before you try to compile and load the `main.cljs`. In this case, this trick works fine. 
Maybe the problem is that the `secondfile.cljs` (and the `def my-var` ) didn't exist before the cljsbuild compilation, so when you tried to use this `my-var` this code wasn't available

I hope this helps you
Juan

Comment: This was it. Having to compile them using the brepl is a bit cumbersome, but it works. Another option that seems to work is alphabetical order. The compiler seems to use file-seq which uses the file.listFiles() which doesn't guarantee order, but at the very least works most of the time and it's easier (and in the end it really doesn't matter, just gets rid of the warnings).